# onCheckedChanged does not seem to work

Tags: android

I have a checkbox. It is set to true or false depending on if a task is done or not (its a manual change). When the task is done I want the textview label to change frmo not done to done and vice versa. So I have the following code. When they click the checkbox the onCheckedChanged method does get fired off. It chooses sets the string depending on if it is true or false correctly. But then it just exits. I get no error in the logs or on the screen but when I step through the program after it sets the string in the onCheckedChanged method it just exits the getView method completely. I cant understand what is going wrong. Theres a small problem in the first couple lines that the logic for setting if the box is true or false is not entirely correct but thats fine I can fix that no problem. I just cant understand why I cant update the label after clickign the checkbox. Any help would be great.

```
final CheckBox statusView = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
        //statusView.setChecked(true);
        if(toDoItem.getStatus().toString().compareTo(ToDoItem.Status.DONE.toString()) == 0)
            statusView.setChecked(true);
        else
            statusView.setChecked(false);

        // TODO - Must also set up an OnCheckedChangeListener,
        // which is called when the user toggles the status checkbox

        statusView
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"Entered onCheckedChanged()");

                        if(isChecked)
                            statusLabelValue = "Done";
                        else
                            statusLabelValue = "Not Done";
                    }
                });

        TextView statusLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.StatusLabel);
        statusLabel.setText(statusLabelValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to change the textview's text in the listener:

```
    statusView
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Entered onCheckedChanged()");

                    if(isChecked)
                        statusLabelValue = "Done";
                    else
                        statusLabelValue = "Not Done";
                    ((TextView)(convertView.findViewById(R.id.StatusLabel))).setText(statusLabelValue);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Right. To clarify a bit, the reason the label is not updated is because the code inside the onCheckedChanged method is not executed until after you click the checkbox. This means that you are setting your label to a default value and then coming back later and updating that value, but not informing the textview that it needs to change.

Comment: Cool that really helps. Cheers lads. Just a follow up question though. This is all done in the getView method of a custom Adapter class. If I want to pass information from the method (view, position, etc) to the onCheckedChanged method whats the best way? I get an error saying variables need to be final to be accessed from an inner class. I can get over this using global variables but I assume that isnt the correct way to deal with this issue?

Comment: @discodowney Frankly, I cannot think of another serious alternative to the two you mentioned. Usually, I make parameters either final or elevate them to fields, besides final local variables and parameters look ugly, so I often prefer the second option :)